# Real thing about "->" and "."

Tags: c, compiler-construction, struct

I always wanted to know what is the real thing difference of how the compiler see a pointer to a struct (in C suppose) and a struct itself.

```
struct person p;
struct person *pp;
```

`pp->age`, I always imagine that the compiler does: "value of pp + offset of atribute "age" in the struct".

But what it does with `person.p`? It would be almost the same. For me "the programmer", p is not a memory address, its like "the structure itself", but of course this is not how the compiler deal with it.

My guess is it's more of a syntactic thing, and the compiler always does `(&p)->age`.

I'm correct?

Comment: Not to hijack the question, but as a student I'm curious in what area would one learn about this sort of thing.  Compiler design? (i mean, obviously I learned (*p).q is the same as p->q in my c++ class)

Comment: Usually a low-level computer systems course (the kind that deals with memory allocation, stack frames, et cetera).

Comment: Thanks - i'm only a sophomore so I'm sure we'll get there eventually

Comment: +1 Interesting/good question.

Comment: Several languages use one syntax for both cases. Anyone know why C doesn't?

Comment: @BCS: ditto. `.` is only valid with struct variables, never with pointers; `->` is only valid with pointers to structs, never with struct variables. Since C is statically typed, the compiler can always disambiguate. None of the answers so far explains the need for two separate operators.

Comment: @BCS I picked up on the idea somehow that once it became apparent to K&R (or maybe just K or just R) that `(*p).x` was a way more common thing than `*(p.x)` (and the period visually breaks up the expression so that you'd maybe expect `*p.x` to mean the first anyway) and that they'd shanked on the precedence tower, `->` was introduced to paper over their mistake.

Comment: @sgm: so remind me what does `*p.x` parse as now?

Comment: @BCS as *(p.x) member has higher precedence than dereference.

Answer (score 28):

`p->q` is essentially syntactic sugar for `(*p).q` in that it dereferences the pointer `p` and then goes to the proper field `q` within it. It saves typing for a very common case (pointers to structs).

In essence, `->` does *two*  deferences (pointer dereference, field dereference) while `.` only does one (field dereference).

Due to the multiple-dereference factor, `->` can't be completely replaced with a static address by the compiler and will always include at least address computation (pointers can change dynamically at runtime, thus the locations will also change), whereas in some cases, `.` operations can be replaced by the compiler with an access to a fixed address (since the base struct's address can be fixed as well).

Comment: Ok. But my question is what is exactly "p" to the compiler?, its also an address, isnt it?. But for me the programmer is "the structure itself"

Comment: Assuming `p` is a local variable, it's an offset within the stack.

Comment: Just can't agree with calling that anything like 'sugar', it has always being the syntax that annoys me the most on C! Would call 'shortcut', a fugly one.. +1 for great explain

Comment: @Fabiano - "syntactic sugar" is a fairly common term in the CS world: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar

Comment: And whats the difference (for the compiler) of  pp  and *pp

Comment: `pp` is "the value contained in memory where the variable pp is stored". `*pp` is "the value contained in some other memory which begins at the address that is contained in the memory where the variable pp is stored"

Comment: and "." does a offset thing I guess. 
Im satisfied.

Comment: @Amber - Not saying you are wrong, just saying I don't agree about it being sugar, see your link: "It makes the language "sweeter" for humans to use", for me that is sour, I would like if it were instead: '..', then it is sugar...

Comment: @Fabiano PS:  "Syntactic sugar" is a pretty standard term (and Dijkstra said it can cause "cancer of the semicolon").  Bear in mind that some people don't like sugar (and would you really prefer `(*p).` to `p->`?).

Comment: @fsdfa - The answer to your question about `p`.  At runtime `p` doesn't really exist.  It exists implicitly in the code that's used to modify a specific set of memory locations. At compile time `p` is just a name the compiler internally uses to represent a set of memory locations an operation is being done on.  Frequently the compiler doesn't know what those memory locations are, except that they exist as offsets to other memory locations that are only known at runtime (such as the stack pointer).  So `p` generally does not ever exist anywhere as an actual pointer.

Answer (score 5):

***Updated*** (see comments):

You have the right idea, but there is an important difference *for global and static variables only*: when the compiler sees `p.age` for a global or static variable, it can replace it, at compile time, with the exact address of the `age` field within the struct.

In contrast, `pp->age` *must* be compiled as "value of pp + offset of `age` field", since the value of pp can change at runtime.

Comment: If it is declared on the stack it doesn't know the exact address at compile time, only the offset against the stack pointer.

Comment: When it sees p.age it knows the **offset** within the struct, but doesn't (unless it's a global variable) know the absolute address of the struct.

Comment: To whomever reversed their downvote: thank you! I've never seen that done before `:)`

Answer (score 3):

The two statements are not equivalent, even from the "compiler perspective". The statement `p.age` translates to the address of `p` + the offset of `age`, while `pp->age` translates to the address *contained in* `pp` + the offset of `age`.

The address *of* a variable and the address *contained in* a (pointer) variable are very different things.

Say the offset of age is 5. If `p` is a structure, its address might be 100, so `p.age` references address 105.

But if `pp` is a pointer to a structure, its address might be 100, but the value stored at address 100 is not the beginning of a `person` structure, it's a pointer. So the value at address 100 (the address *contained in* `pp`) might be, for example, 250. In that case, `pp->age` references address 255, not 105.

Comment: In other words, reading from `p.age` conceptually requires one memory read, from the (known) location of `p` plus the offset of `age`.  Whereas reading from `pp->age` conceptually requires two memory reads - one from the location of `pp`, then a second from the location given by the first read plus the offset of `age`.

Answer (score 1):

Since p is a local (automatic) variable, it is stored in the stack. Therefore the compiler accesses it in terms of offset with regard to the stack pointer (SP) or frame pointer (FP or BP, in architectures where it exists). In contrast, *p refers to a memory address [usually] allocated  in the heap, so the stack registers are not used.

Comment: You can pass a stack-allocated struct by address to a subroutine: in which case the pointer received by the subroutine is to an object on the stack.

Comment: @ChrisW: Good point. Of course, the compiler still accesses the struct as a straightforward address (without using SP).

Answer (score 1):

This is a question I've always asked myself.

`v.x`, the *member* operator, is valid **only** for structs.
`v->x`, the *member of pointer* operator, is valid **only** for struct pointers.

So why have two different operators, since only one is needed? For example, only the `.` operator could be used; the compiler always knows the type of `v`, so it knows what to do: `v.x` if `v` is a struct, `(*v).x` if `v` is a struct pointer.

I have three theories:

- temporary shortsightedness by K&R (which theory I'd like to be false)
- making the job easier for the compiler (a practical theory, given the conception time of C :)
- readability (which theory I prefer)

Unfortunately, I don't know which one (if any) is true.

Answer (score 0):

In both cases the structure and its members are addressed by

**address(person) + offset(age)**

Using p with a struct stored in the stack memory gives the compiler more options to optimize memory usage. It could store the age only, instead of the whole struct if nothing else is used - this makes addressing with the above function fail (I think reading the address of a struct stops this optimization).
A struct on the stack may have no memory address at all. If the struct is small enough and only lives a short time it can be mapped to some of the processors registers (same as for the optimization above for reading the address).

**The short answer: when the compiler does not optimize you are right. As soon as the compiler starts optimizing only what the c standard specifies is guaranteed**.

Edit: Removed flawed stack/heap location for "pp->" since the pointed to struct can be on both heap and stack.

Comment: The location of the variable has *nothing* to do with the addressing mode used to access it. With `pp->` the structure could be anywhere, heap, stack, “global”. With `p.` the structure can be in any of the above too except for heap memory ('cos you can't declare variables there directly). I always like to think of pointers as being like arrows, pointing to arrays of memory cells. As analogies go, it seems easy and not that far wrong.

Comment: @Donal Fellows you are right about "pp->" I only thought about the simplest use case. If age was a struct you could address it with pp->age.days so the "." doesn't say much about the memory location either.

Comment: That's true. The difference isn't related to location, but rather whether you've got the name of a thing (i.e., a pointer to it) or the thing itself (the memory cell/structure/array/…; in Kantian philosophy “Ding an sich”).